# Multiple keyword search on MongoDB using c#?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am trying to create a mongodb query in c# that will allow me to search a single field for multiple keywords. I can only find answers for using a single keyword. I am using MongoDB.Driver v2.6.1

My model:

```
  public class RBpartsImages
    {
        [BsonId]
        public ObjectId ID { get; set; }
        public String PartNum { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public String ImageFilename { get; set; }
        public ImgSize ImageSize { get; set; }
    }
```

This works, but only with a single keyword:

```
        String keywords = "beam thin"; // produces no results, 
        // String keywords="beam"; // gives results
        var filter = Builders<RBpartsImages>.Filter.Regex("Name", new BsonRegularExpression(keywords, @"(?i)[^\s,;]+"));
        List<RBpartsImages> query = imagesCollection.Find(filter).ToList();

        Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("GetRBparts: {0}", query.ToJson(new JsonWriterSettings { Indent = true })));
        // the output is paged
        rbParts = query.Skip(page * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();
```

and this gives an 'Unsupported filter: Any(value' error:

```
    String keywords = "beam thin";
    List<String> kWords = Regex.Split(keywords, @"[\s,;]+").ToList();
    Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("GetRBparts: {0}", kWords.ToJson(new JsonWriterSettings { Indent = true })));
    List<RBpartsImages> query = (from rbi in imagesCollection.AsQueryable()
                 where (kWords.Any(r => rbi.Name.ToLower().Contains(r)))
                 select rbi).ToList();
```

I am looking for a way for the user to filter the returned list by keywords, any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just confirmed we had a unit test that does this. Here's a snip:

```
var filterList = new List<string>{"TEST","test","12345"};
Func<TestDataModel, bool> wherePredicate = 
               (data) => filterList.Any(f => data.Detail.Contains(f));
var results = collection.AsQueryable().Where(wherePredicate).ToList();
```

In order to use the Regex filter (as per your first attempt), you'll want to make some minor changes:

```
string keywords = "beam thin";
var regex = $"(.*{keywords.Replace(" ", ".*)|(.*")})";
var filter = Builders<RBpartsImages>.Filter.Regex("Name", new BsonRegularExpression(regex));
List<RBpartsImages> query = imagesCollection.Find(filter).ToList();
...
```

The problem was that when creating the BsonRegularExpression model, you were passing in the list of keywords plus an expression, when it actually takes an expression plus options (such as case insensitive search, etc). By manipulating the keywords string into a valid regex string you'll get the results you expected.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Right idea, but the extra twist is the searches are on regular expressions and not just an exact match for the word. You only need make a small change to make that work though.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't see where (data) comes from, using RBpartsImages data = new RBpartsImages(); didn't work.

Comment: (data) is just the alias for the datatype being used. I'll update my example to be clearer. Sorry

Comment: it sort of works, in that it finds all entries that contain "beam" or "thin", when I want only the entries that have both "beam" and "thin".  But changing the.Any  to "=> kWords.All(f =>" appears to have worked. Thanks.